# Pytest can't find files/modules

Tags: pytest, directory-structure, code-structure

I have had a look at several different topics on this matter but can't work out how to apply it to my situation. I don't have an init.py in my test folder and I have tried to use `conftest`. I have a directory structure like this:

```
--app
    --app.py
    --src
        --init.py
        --module1.py
        --module2.py
        --module3.py
    --configs
         --config.json
         --non-default-config.json
    --tests
        --test1.py
    --conftest.py
```

where `app.py` imports module1, which then imports modules 2&3 (using `import src.module2`). I load up `config.json` in all the modules files (and app.py) using:

```
with open('configs/config.json') as f:
    CFG = json.load(f)
```

This works when I run `app.py` from the app directory. However, when I run `pytest` (which I believe should also be referencing from the app directory, since conftest.py is in the app directory) and it imports module1 (using `import src.module1`), it cannot find `configs/config.json`, but will find `app/configs/config.json`. I cannot use this as it will cause my app to break when I run `app.py`. However, Pytest can find the imports from within the src folder, even though this is on the same level as the configs folder.

If I move the `conftest.py` outside of the app directory and import module1 using `import app.src.module1` then this import succeeds, but the import of module2 inside module1 then fails.

How can I resolve this issue? And is there a better way of structuring my project?

Comment: I realised I can run pytest from inside of the app folder to make it work. However, if there are any structural improvements anyone can suggest then this would still be helpful :) Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried renaming `src/init.py` to `src/__init__.py`? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sorry I made an error when typing the name, it is already called `src/__init__.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by running pytest from inside the app folder instead of from the base directory.